# Checking Out Directory / File with SVNKit

Tags: java, svnkit

I can't see on the wiki where checking out is documented. Ideally, I would like to check out a file "example/folder/file.xml", if not just the folder... and then when the application closes down or otherwise, be able to commit back in changes to this file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot check out a file in Subversion.  You have to check out a folder.

To check out a folder with one or more files:

```java
SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(null, 
            repository.getAuthenticationManager());
SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
updateClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
updateClient.doCheckout(url, destPath, revision, revision,
            isRecursive);
```

To commit a previously checked out folder:

```java
SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(null, 
            repository.getAuthenticationManager());
ourClientManager.getWCClient().doInfo(wcPath, SVNRevision.HEAD);
ourClientManager.getCommitClient().doCommit
        (new File[] { wcPath }, keepLocks, commitMessage, false, true);
```

Comment: +1 very useful answer. In addition, if you want to **export** a file then you can do this using [`updateClient.doExport(url, destPath, revision, revision, eolStyle, force, isRecursive)`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNUpdateClient.html#doExport%28org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL,%20java.io.File,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

Comment: The listed overload of doExport is deprecated in SVNKit 1.7.5-v1. Instead I used the following overload: `updateClient.doCheckout(url, destPath, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);`

Comment: On using the above code I'm getting a warning "The method doCheckout(SVNURL, File, SVNRevision, SVNRevision, boolean) from the type SVNUpdateClient is deprecated"...Any idea which method to use instead of doCheckout??

Answer (score 21):

As SVNKit developer, I would recommend you to prefer new API based on SvnOperationFactory. The old API (based on SVNClientManager) will be operational still but all new SVN features will come only to the new API.

```
final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {
    final SvnCheckout checkout = svnOperationFactory.createCheckout();
    checkout.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory));
    checkout.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(url));
    //... other options
    checkout.run();
} finally {
    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

Comment: so we have to declare workingCopyDirectory as "File workingCopyDirectory=new File("/home/lucy");" ???

Comment: ok..I have another doubt..Will SvnOperationFactory copy a folder also along with files stored at a particukar SVN path or just the files??

Comment: It will behave in the same manner as `svn co <url> <workingCopyDirectory>` does: `workingCopyDirectory` will contain the same files and directories as `url` does.

Comment: I have used the above code twice to checkout 2 directories from svn. Is there a better way of doing it??

Comment: No, there's no way to checkout several working copies in one operation.

Comment: So what i have done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099430/checkout-multiple-directories-from-svn-using-svn-kit  is correct??

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to do that.

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko I'm trying to checkout from a repository (dump | load) in my machine and the URL is :-

SVNURL secondUrl = SVNURL.fromFile(new File("/home/vsharma/svn/API_Work/hotcopy/test")); 
but i'm getting exceptions:- 

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/vsharma/svn/API_Work/hotcopy/test'
svn: E125006: '/home/vsharma/svn/API_Work/hotcopy/test/db/format' contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing logical'
Any way to make it work?

Comment: 'addressing logical' feature was added in later SVNKit versions (>=1.8.12), so retry with the latest version. Also I would like to note that "checkout" operation has nothing to do with "svnadmin dump/load". For "svnadmin" commands look at SVNAdminClient class.

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko Anything over 1.8.7 is crashing JRE even in debugger.

Comment: That is probably related to Gnome Keyring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342816/jre-getting-crashed-when-using-svnkit-inside-a-web-app-on-tomcat-server/43208098#43208098 I've fixed the issue in SVNKit repository but we didn't publish a release yet. For now you can either turn Gnome Keyring off, or wait for the next release (it will be soon), or build SVNKit from sources.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the code snippet proposed by Dmitry Pavlenko and I had no problems.
But it took nearly 30 minutes to checkout or update a repo struture of 35 MB.
It's not useable in my usecase (simply checking out a directory structure as part of the content/documents/media of a web application).
Or have I made some errors?

```
final ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
final SVNURL svnUrl = SVNURL.create(url.getProtocol(), name, url.getHost(), 443, url.getPath(), true);

SVNRepository svnRepo= SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnUrl);
svnRepo.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

SVNDirEntry entry = svnRepo.info(".", -1);
long remoteRevision = entry.getRevision();

if (!workingCopyDirectory.exists()) {
    workingCopyDirectory.mkdirs();
}

final SvnCheckout checkout = svnOperationFactory.createCheckout();
checkout.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(svnUrl));
checkout.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory));
remoteRevision = checkout.run();
```

Comment: I have the same problem, it take forever to finish... There must a parameter missing. Did you ever get it solved?