# User doc for new Svnkit Api?

Tags: svnkit

There seems to exist some new SVNKit API under "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2"  based on SvnOperationFactory according to some answers to svnkit questions: [svnkitquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395322/checking-out-directory-file-with-svnkit).

Yet i cannot find any documentation on how to use this / examples. The only thing is found is the [javadoc](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc2/SvnOperationFactory.html) to the class, which doesnt really help you as a user of the api.

Where can i find the user documentation for the new api?

Cheers!

Comment: At this moment --- nowhere. You can use javadoc and tests in SVNKit as examples.

Comment: ok, this seems to be the url to the tests: http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/svnkit/src/test/java/org/tmatesoft/svn/test/